# How to calculate a fee where the fee percentage changes for different amounts of the number? vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqGvrr?editors=1000

Im trying to write a program to calculate a fee for a building cost. The user enters a number and then it calculates the builder fee based on that number.

The first 5000 of the building is 8%.

Another 3% for the *remainder* up to and including 80,000,

**OR** 2.5% if the *remainder* is more than 80,000.

I have the first 5000 dealt with a simple if statement. I know i should finish the other 2 conditions with else if statements but i cant think of how to "target" only a certain portion of the user's entered number? aka if they enter 70,000 how do i target the first 5000 for 8%, *then* apply 3% fee to the remaining 65,000...etc. Thanks!

P.S. sorry for the annoying window prompt in codepen lol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function part04() {

            //    Define all variables 
            var costOfBuilding;
            var builderFee;
            var outputMessage;

            //    Obtain building cost from user
            costOfBuilding = prompt('What is the cost of the building?');

            //    Convert user string to a number
            costOfBuilding = Number(costOfBuilding);

            //    Calculate builder fee
            if (costOfBuilding <= 5000) {
                builderFee = costOfBuilding * .08;
                outputMessage = 'For a building that costs $'
                                + costOfBuilding
                                + ' the architect\'s fee will be $'
                                + architectFee
                                + '.';
            } 

            //    Display output message with building cost and builder fee
            document.write(outputMessage);
        }
    </script>

    <pre>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        part04();
      </script>
     </pre>

   </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE. Answer below lead me to answer, just had to make a few adjustments to fit the formula properly. Thanks Everyone!

```
if (costOfBuilding <= 5000) {
    builderFee = costOfBuilding * .08;
} else if (costOfBuilding > 5000 && costOfBuilding <= 85000) {
    remainingCost = costOfBuilding - 5000;
    builderFee = (5000 * .08) + remainingCost * .03;
} else if (costOfBuilding > 85000) {
    remainingCost = costOfBuilding - 5000;
    builderFee = (5000 * .08) + remainingCost * .025;
}

    outputMessage = 'For a building that costs $'
                    + costOfBuilding
                    + ' the architect\'s fee will be $'
                    + builderFee
                    + '.';
```

Comment: `OR 2.5% if the remainder is more than 80,000.` Just to make sure, this sounds like if the total is 85,001, the total fee will be less than if the total is 84,999?

Comment: For `outputMessage = 'For a building that costs $'...` part, it is common so you can move it after `if...else...` conditions it will reduce your code.

Comment: @Karan ah good idea. Thanks! just made a small edit to your suggestion to keep the correct .03 and .025 in the proper else if statement.

Answer (score 3):

Update your calculation as below and remove `if` condition.:

```
architectFee = (Math.min(costOfBuilding, 5000) * 0.08) + (Math.max(costOfBuilding - 5000, 0) * (costOfBuilding > 80000 ? 0.025 : 0.03));
```

```js
function part04() {

  //    Define all variables 
  var costOfBuilding;
  var architectFee;
  var outputMessage;

  //    Obtain building cost from user
  costOfBuilding = prompt('What is the cost of the building?');

  //    Convert user string to a number
  costOfBuilding = Number(costOfBuilding);

  //    Calculate architect's fee

  //architectFee = (Math.min(costOfBuilding, 5000) * 0.08) + (Math.max(costOfBuilding - 5000, 0) * 0.03) + (Math.max(costOfBuilding - 80000, 0) * 0.025);
  architectFee = (Math.min(costOfBuilding, 5000) * 0.08) + (Math.max(costOfBuilding - 5000, 0) * (costOfBuilding > 80000 ? 0.025 : 0.03));

  outputMessage = 'For a building that costs $' +
    costOfBuilding +
    ' the architect\'s fee will be $' +
    architectFee +
    '.';


  //    Display output message with building cost and architect fee
  document.write(outputMessage);
}

part04();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are 3 conditions you're dealing with: less than 5000, more than 5000 but less than 80,000, and more than 80,000. In the two cases that aren't written yet you can save the remaining cost and calculate the additional cost with it.

So you can have your remaining items like this:

```
else if (costOfBuilding <= 80,000) {
   var remainingCost = costOfBuilding - 5000;
   architectFee = 5000 * .08 + remainingCost * .03;
}
else {
   var remainingCost = costOfBuilding - 5000;
   architectFee = 5000 * .08 + remainingCost * .025;
}
```